# This Gruntfile is outputting a file called "dest" instead of a css file in the path I've supplied. Why?

Tags: gruntjs

This Gruntfile is outputting a file called "dest" in the root of my project, instead of a css file in assets/css. Why?

```html
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pure_grids: {
            dest : 'assets/css/main-grid.css',

            options: {
                units: 12, // 12-column grid

                mediaQueries: {
                    sm: 'screen and (min-width: 35.5em)', // 568px
                    md: 'screen and (min-width: 48em)',   // 768px
                    lg: 'screen and (min-width: 64em)',   // 1024px
                    xl: 'screen and (min-width: 80em)'    // 1280px
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-pure-grids');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['pure_grids']);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grunt-pure-grids` plugin is a [Multi-task plugin](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks), you may need to update your config and wrap the settings you've defined within a `target`.  The example below wraps your settings within a target called `foo`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pure_grids: {
        foo: {
            dest : 'assets/css/main-grid.css',

            options: {
                units: 12, // 12-column grid

                mediaQueries: {
                    sm: 'screen and (min-width: 35.5em)', // 568px
                    md: 'screen and (min-width: 48em)',   // 768px
                    lg: 'screen and (min-width: 64em)',   // 1024px
                    xl: 'screen and (min-width: 80em)'    // 1280px
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to file an issue with the grunt plugin's owner, but be aware that `grunt-pure-grids` hasn't been updated in 2 years, it may now be orphaned.

Comment: That did the trick! Am new to grunt, so just learned something. Thanks!